# Unable to render 2D image in android open GLES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, texture2d

I tried to render some 2D object and I am able to do that but now I tried to render some images in opengl but it not showing anything. Here is my image rendering code .

```
package com.example.androidinternalmaps;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;

public class ImageObject 
{
    private final Context mActivityContext;

    private final FloatBuffer mCubeTextureCoordinates;
    private int mTextureUniformHandle;
    private int mTextureCoordinateHandle;
    private final int mTextureCoordinateDataSize = 2;
    private int mTextureDataHandle;

    private final String VerShader = 
    "uniform mat4 u_Matrix;"+
    "attribute vec4 a_Position;"+  
    "attribute vec2 a_TextureCoordinates;"+
    "varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;"+
    "void main()"+                    
    "{"+                            
        "v_TextureCoordinates = a_TextureCoordinates;"+       
        "gl_Position = u_Matrix * a_Position;"+    
    "}";

    private final String FragShader = 
            "precision mediump float;"+ 
            "uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit;"+                                         
            "varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;"+                                       
            "void main()"+                          
            "{"+                                
                "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates);"+                                   
            "}";

    private final int shaderProgram;    
    private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2;
    static float spriteCoords[] = { -0.5f,  0.5f,   // top left
                                -0.5f, -0.5f,   // bottom left
                                 0.5f, -0.5f,   // bottom right
                                 0.5f,  0.5f }; //top right

    private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; //Order to draw vertices
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; //Bytes per vertex

    float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };

    public ImageObject(final Context activityContext)
    {
        mActivityContext = activityContext;

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(spriteCoords.length * 4); 
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(spriteCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        final float[] cubeTextureCoordinateData =
        {                                               
            -0.5f,  0.5f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f,
             0.5f, -0.5f,
             0.5f,  0.5f
        };

        mCubeTextureCoordinates = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(cubeTextureCoordinateData.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        mCubeTextureCoordinates.put(cubeTextureCoordinateData).position(0);

        //Initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(spriteCoords.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, VerShader);
        int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, FragShader);

        shaderProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

        //Texture Code
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "a_TexCoordinate");

        GLES20.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

        //Load the texture
        mTextureDataHandle = loadTexture(mActivityContext, R.drawable.air_hockey_surface);
    }

    public void Draw(float[] mvpMatrix)
    {
        //Add program to OpenGL ES Environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        //Get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vPosition");

        //Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        //Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        //Get Handle to Fragment Shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "vColor");

        //Set the Color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        //Set Texture Handles and bind Texture
        mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "u_Texture");
        mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_TexCoordinate");

        //Set the active texture unit to texture unit 0.
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);

        //Bind the texture to this unit.
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle);

        //Tell the texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by binding to texture unit 0.
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0); 

        //Pass in the texture coordinate information
        mCubeTextureCoordinates.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, mTextureCoordinateDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mCubeTextureCoordinates);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);

        //Get Handle to Shape's Transformation Matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

        //Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

        //Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

        //Disable Vertex Array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }

    public static int loadTexture(final Context context, final int resourceId)
    {
        final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

        if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
        {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;   // No pre-scaling

        // Read in the resource
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        bitmap.recycle();
        }

        if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
        {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
        }

        return textureHandle[0];
    }
}
```

It is not showing anything. Just blank screen. I Don't know what I am doing wrong. Need Help. Thank you .

My renderer class

```
package com.example.androidinternalmaps;


import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;

public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private FloorPolygon floorPolygon;
    private ImageObject imageObject;
    private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];

    private float originX = 0.0f, originY = 0.0f;
    private float translationDx=0.0f,translationDy=0.0f;
    private float originScaleX = 2.5f, originScaleY = 2.5f;
    private float scaleDx = 1.0f, scaleDy = 1.0f; 
    private float surfaceViewWidth, surfaceViewHeight;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyGLRenderer(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    floorPolygon = new FloorPolygon();
    imageObject = new ImageObject(mContext);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) 
    {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mMVPMatrix, 0, originX+translationDx, originY+translationDy, 0.0f);
    Matrix.scaleM(mMVPMatrix, 0, scaleDx*originScaleX, scaleDy*originScaleY, 0.0f);

    imageObject.Draw(mMVPMatrix);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) 
    {
        surfaceViewHeight = height;
        surfaceViewWidth = width;

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
    }

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode)
    {
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
    }

    public void setTranslationPoints(float translationDx, float translationDy)
    {
        this.translationDx = ((translationDx/surfaceViewWidth)*2);
        this.translationDy = -((translationDy/surfaceViewHeight)*2);
    }

    public void setScalePoints(float scaleDx, float scaleDy)
    {
        this.scaleDx = scaleDx;
        this.scaleDy = scaleDy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the dimensions of your textures a power of two? Try calling GLES20.glClearColor to set your background to something other than black. If you can see your object rendered all in black then it's a texture problem. Where do you set the projection and view matrix? Are you sure you're looking at the object?

Comment: OK let me put all code. And my texture dimensions are power of two.

Comment: I changes background color to white. And no black texture rendering :(. Any problem in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue I think is this:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Your look vector is (0,0,0) which doesn't describe a direction. Your eye position is (0,0,5), indicating a position towards you along the z-axis from the origin. So your look vector needs to be away from you back towards the origin. Therefore try changing the look vector to (0,0,-1):

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0f, 0f, -1f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

EDIT:

For starters, move this to onSurfaceChanged since you don't need to call it on every frame, just when the surface gets constructed:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0f, 0f, -1f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Now for the ImageObject class. In your vertex shader, change 'a_TextureCoordinates' to 'a_TexCoordinate' so that the name matches what you use in your constructor code.

In the constructor, make this change:

```
//GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "a_TexCoordinate");
GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "a_Position");
GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 1, "a_TexCoordinate");
```

Before you were binding "a_TexCoordinate" to position 0 but it should be position 1 since it's the 2nd attribute in the shader. The first attribute in your shader is "a_Position" so should be bound to position 0.

In Draw, make these changes:

```
//mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vPosition");
mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_Position");

//mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "u_Texture");
mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_TextureUnit");

//mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_Matrix");
```

That's because the names don't match up correctly with the names in the shaders. For the texture handler, this is a Uniform, not an Attribute hence you need to use glGetUniformLocation.

That should be it I think. I've run your code and I'm getting a texture drawn across the screen.

Comment: Thank you for replay. I tried your solution but its not working.Is there any good tutorial regarding rending images in android open gles 2.0? Thank you for help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been busy examining your code - it's been an enjoyable and useful revision exercise for me (not done this stuff for a few months).